# Displaying '.hidden' elements using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this asp and HTML code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row1">
                <table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td rowspan="7">
                             <input type="button" class="toggleRow" value="B" style="height: 30px; position: relative; float: left;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>text:</td>
                        <td rowspan="4">
                            <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>text:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Text") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>X:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lon") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>Y:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lat") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>      
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript code:

```
        $('.toggleRow').on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('table').children('.hidden').show();

            return false;
        });
```

When batten with class toggleRow clicked the javascript fired but I do not get any result (i.e I expect the hidden row will be displayed but the not).

Any idea why?

Comment: Try  `$('tr').toggleClass('.hidden');`

Comment: Maybe I missed something but I don't see any element with toggleRow class in your code!

Comment: if you are referring to this `#btnToggleRow` button your click is wrong.

Comment: @JeanRAKOTO I updted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `table` and `tr`, even though you are not creating `tbody` the browser will put all the `tr` elements in a `tbody`, so your selector `$(this).closest('table').children('.hidden').show();` will not be able to find the `tr` as children of the able.

So try

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tr.hidden').show();
```

You also will have to add the `toggleRow` class to the button

```
<input type="button" id="btnToggleRow" value="B" style="height: 30px; position: relative; float: left;" class="toggleRow"/>
```

Comment: I did not understand why do I have tr.hidden instead of .hidden?Can you please explain it more properly?

Comment: @Michael could have a hidden input with a class hidden it would show up if you dont specify `tr.hidden` this way only tr with class hidden will show up

Comment: You can remove tr in tr.hidden if you wish. This is just to be more specific. The real problem is in the children function. To replace with find.

Answer (score 0):

To display the row which are hidden use below code.

```
$('.toggleRow').on('click', function () {
    $('.hidden').css("display","block");
    return false;
});
```